# Debugger says my variable isn't defined, but I bought it out with return() in a function

Tags: python

Im doing this homework assignment, but when i want to print the final variable the debugger says the variable isnt defined but I think i define it and bring it out of the funtion with return(). What's wrong?My goal is to convert kilometers into miles.

```
kilometers=float(input('How many Kilometers?'))

def converter(kilometers):
    miles= kilometers*(1.60934)
    return (str(miles))


print (miles)
```

Comment: Now if you _call_ your function, the value will be returned from the function call.

Comment: You need to call your function. In the code above, you've defined it but not called it.

Answer (score 1):

`miles` is a local variable, only visible in the function `converter`. You have to call the function and print the result. Try the following (replace the last line):

```
miles = converter(kilometers)
print(miles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function. Change your print statement to the following:

```
print (converter(kilometers))
```